# Defining arbitary Derivatives of functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

If I have two functions like these `f[a_,b_]` and `g[a_,b_]`. Lets say

```
f[a_,b_]:= a^2 + b 
g[a_,b_]:= a + b
```

some times I encounter
`Dt[f[a,b] , g[a,b]]` and I want to have a defined value for this derivative,
like 
 `Dt[f[a,b] , g[a,b]]-> R1`
How can I define new derivative for this problem in *Mathematica*?

I mean whenever I differentiate `f` with respect `g` I get `R1`.

Comment: I think in order to know the correct way to do this, we need more context about your problem (and the previous question you asked doesn't contain enough context).

Comment: I tried to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

```
protected = Unprotect[Dt]
```

> {"Dt"}

```
Dt[f[___], g[___]] := R1

Dt[f[a, b], g[]]
```

> R1

Clear your definition

```
Clear@Dt

Dt[f[], g[]]
```

> 0

Remember

If your definition is no longer needed `Clear` it - otherwise you might get unwanted results in other areas. And restore protection:

```
Protect[Evaluate[protected]]
```

> {"Dt"}

Answer (score 2):

Problem with defining such derivatives is that `Dt` doesn't hold its arguments, so if `f` and `g` have some definitions

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f[a_, b_] := a^2 + b
g[a_, b_] := a + b
```

then they are evaluated when passed to `Dt`, so "standard trick" with defining `UpValues` like:

```
f /: Dt[HoldPattern@f[a_, b_], HoldPattern@g[a_, b_]] := r1[a, b]
```

will not work.

What you can do is to use an "environment", in which this derivative will have desired value.

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f[a_, b_] := a^2 + b
g[a_, b_] := a + b

ClearAll[withMyDerivative]
SetAttributes[withMyDerivative, HoldFirst]
withMyDerivative[expr_] :=
    Block[{g},
        g /: Dt[f[a_, b_], g[a_, b_]] := r1[a, b];
        expr
    ]
```

Now, inside `withMyDerivative` environment, `Dt[f[a_, b_], g[a_, b_]]` will evaluate to `r1[a, b]`.

```
g[a, b] (f[a, b] + Dt[f[a, b], g[a, b]]) // withMyDerivative
(* (a + b) (a^2 + b + r1[a, b]) *)
```